# ASP .NET MVC4 Change language of all ValidationMessages at one fell swoop

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am programming a webapp. When I run it in my pc it shows ValidationMessages in spanish, but when I run it in another server it shows them in english.

[image: Image showing the unwanted behaviour]

What I want is them to be shown in **spanish**. Both pc's regional configurations are set to Spanish (Argentina).

When I display...

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.DisplayName
```

on each pc, mine says "Inglés (Estados Unidos)", and the other says "English(United States)".

I could change this *a little*. To test, I added this to the Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"); //en-US just to test
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"); //en-US just to test
    }
```

This affected in my pc the aforementioned Culture display. It said "English(United States)" and the messages were displayed in english.

However, when I tested this in the server

```
    protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-AR");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-AR");
    }
```

the message did not change, and the ValidationMessages continued being displayed in english.

I even installed .NET Language Pack in the server, but no luck. What can I do to change this behavior?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to say, the webconfig already has:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="es-AR" culture="es-AR" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The localised message will depend on the locale of the client, though it looks like you are setting the server locale?

Comment: I am obtaining different results from the different servers, despite my pc being the client in both cases.

Comment: Configure this in web.config.

Comment: I already did some configuration. I updated my question; is that section what you meant?